# Emacs truncates some kbd macros during insert-kbd-macro

Tags: emacs, macros

I am trying to customize emacs for my needs. In particular I want to define a long keyboard macro and save it for later use. However emacs seems to truncate the definition during saving.

Environment: Emacs 24.5-7 on Fedora 23

My attempts showed that emacs uses two different formats for saving depending on the keyboard input. For pure textual form without control characters it just stores a string; no truncation occurred so far. However when a control character, even a newline, is part of the input emacs stores a vector of character symbols?() with only the first 12 elements, the rest is just indicated by ellipsis (...) and cannot be used later.

I use C-x C-( and C-x C-) to define the macro, C-x C-k n to give it a name, and then save it with M-x insert-kbd-macro:

13 printable characters:
abcdefghijklm

> (fset 'str13
>     (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote (**"abcdefghijklm"** 0 "%d")) arg)))

11 printable characters with newline:
abcdefghijk

> (fset 'str11nl
>     (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote (**[97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 return]** 0 "%d")) arg)))

12 printable characters with newline:
abcdefghijkl

> (fset 'str12nl
>     (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote (**97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 ...]** 0 "%d")) arg)))

When I load this macro again, e.g. with M-x eval-region and M-x str12nl, only the 12 printable characters are inserted, then an error occurs:

> After 0 kbd macro iterations: Keyboard macro terminated by a command ringing the bell

Is there a method to have the full definition saved?
,

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe on Emacs 24.5.1.  But I have a feeling that the variable `eval-expression-print-length` is likely to be your culprit, or at least related.

Comment: eval-expression-print-length is indeed 12, but increasing it does not help.

Comment: I now use a workaround: I define my keyboard input in form of multiple shorter macros, save them, and manually merge their vectors into one large macro. As a side effect I get to learn the symbols used.